# C#: shield XmlTextReader from an occasional Unicode character

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, stream

In C#, I have a XmlTextReader created directly from an HTTP response (I have no control over the XML content of the response).

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

It works, but sometimes one of the XML element nodes will contain a Unicode character (e.g. "é") which trips the reader. I've tried to use a StreamReader with declared encoding, but now the XmlTextReader quits out on the very first line: "Data invalid. Line 1, position 1":

```
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(sReader);
```

Is there a way to fix this? Alternatively, is there a way to prevent the XmlTextReader from parsing an element (I know its name) with a potentially offending character? I don't care about that particular element, I just don't want it to trip the reader.

EDIT: Quick fix: read the response into a StringBuilder ("sb"):

```
sb.Replace("é", "e");
StringReader strReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a Unicode character, it is an **invalid** character (*not correctly encoded*).

There is no way to shield an `XmlTextReader` from **invalid XML**. You need to either

- Fix the server side to properly encode characters
- Pre-process the text to do it yourself

---

According to UTF8, all such characters ("é") are encoded with **2 or 3 bytes** (or more). You can use a hex editor to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "trips the reader"? Your first snippet of code should be fine - if the XML is genuinely in the encoding it declares (please look at the XML declaration) then it should be absolutely fine.

If the XML is genuinely broken, I would suggest performing some sort of filtering *before* XML parsing (e.g. loading the XML into a string with the right encoding, then fixing the *declared* encoding to match)... but we'll need to work out what's wrong with it first.

Comment: There's no encoding declaration. The 1st line in the HTTP response reads: <Result size="9">... followed by element nodes. The last line is </Result>. The server returns XML-formatted data which may not be 100% perfect XML. I have no control over it. Looks like text filtering is the only option.

Comment: @MrSparkly: Okay, it should detect the encoding based on the stream. Do you know what encoding is *actually* being used? It may not be too hard to just insert your own XML declaration at the start.

Comment: Is inserting my own encoding declaration as simple as adding <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8\></head> at the head of the incoming XML?

Comment: @MrSparkly: No, that's an HTML tag... I mean `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..." ?>` before the opening `<html>` tag.